# Dependence and parallel execution

Tags: powershell, f#, f#-fake

I'm using powershell to automate the execution of programs. The following is one of the simplified scenario.

There are tasks A, A1, A2, X[1..n] and Y[1..n].

1. A1 and A2 cannot be run until A is done. A1 and A2 can be run concurrently.
2. All X cannot be run until A1 is done.
3. All Y cannot be run until A2 is done.
4. Y[n] cannot be run until x[n] is done.

How to implement it powershell so the tasks take the shortest time? Or should it use MSMQ or Sql server service broker with Powershell?

Is F# FAKE a good tool for such automation?

Comment: This sort of thing is frequently achieved with the help of parallel build tools (`make` and its ilk). Granted perfect, or even good, scheduling is a famously hard problem which the tools I've looked at have barely even bothered to attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Start-Job & Wait-Job Cmdlets.  Look at the help files on these, you should be able to do what you need to do with those cmdlets.

If that doesn't do what you need to do you should check out POSHRSJob written by powershell MVP Boe Prox.

https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob